# Creating timeline schedule using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

We are given an assignment to create WPF C# app called `Virtual Classroom Management System`. In this app there are `User`s (`Professor`s, `Assistant`s and `Administrator`s). Any user can book/schedule a classroom by creating `Appointment`s, which will be done by choosing any classroom from the institution to which that user belongs to and stating start and end date of an `Appointment`. Among bunch of functionalities of this app, there is one which I'm interested to hear how to execute :)

This functionality is, her majesty, **the schedule overview**. You can see my lovely [idea](https://ibb.co/YyNt0GB) below, with unparalleled drawing abilities :)

The user should be able to input start date and end date for which he/she wants to see generated schedule for institution (to which he/she belongs).

I need somehow to "`scale`" the timeline with the actual length of an appointment.

This is my first WPF project, I am 2nd year at University. I don't have much knowledge on GUI app's but I can and will learn.

So, If someone can suggest where do I start? What to explore? How to set a layout for this? On which components to relay on? DataGrid, Canvas? How to combine them? Hope I won't get bad reputation for asking this :) Or if this is too difficult, any other ideas on how to do it?

Comment: This is a big task you've been given. It is not a beginner's task if you create it from scratch. There's potentially a LOT to learn here.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you can't use a commercial control :). To be honest, and no offense, you are asking about an Outlook Timeline control which is a very complicated control to do right, but I'll point you in the right direction and assume you just need the basic functionality.

Horizontally, for the first row for example, you wouldn't have 3 rectangles, you'd just have one that stretches the whole width, let's call it 0 to 99 for simplicity.

To give the illusion of 3 rectangles (or however many you want), you'd use a horizontal LinearGradientBrush with "hard transitions".

So lets say you want a blue rectangle from 0 to 10 and a green rectangle from 15 to 20, you would do something like:

```
GradientStop Offset=0, Color=Blue
GradientStop Offset=0.10 Color=Blue   (0.10 = 10/100)
GradientStop Offset=0.10 Color=Transparent         (the transparent will give the illusion of a gap from 10 to 15)
GradientStop Offset=0.15 Color=Transparent
GradientStop Offset=0.15 Color=Green
GradientStop Offset=0.20 Color=Green
```

Note the double offsets, that's the trick to get a hard break with LinearGradientBrush. I.e. you have .10 = Blue AND .10 = Transparent. That'll give you a hard break from Blue to Transparent.

So basically, you'd calculate the width of the entire rectangle and calculate the percentages across where you want rectangles and build your gradient stop collection as I showed.

Makes sense?

Comment: I had same idea, regarding percentages, as a way to set rectangles. I don't know if I make myself clear enough, the timeline needs to be proportional to the length of each appointment, Meaning if one appointment is 17 hours long and some other appointment is 16 hours long, the first one will be slightly longer, depending how big is timeline. Have no idea how to connect these two things....And yeah, non offense taken, thank you for your opinion.

Comment: God damn, https://www.syncfusion.com/wpf-ui-controls/scheduler this thing is like 1000 bucks for WPF verision :) Is this some sort of library to be installed? Is there anything similar only free :D

Comment: I'd look at telerik rather than syncfusion and ask them about student discount. You should download their trial version if they still do that. Depending on the nature of your project that might be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: @MiljanPuletic I explained how to build a "student" version of it. Whats the issue? If rect 1 is 10,  you make the gradient stop 0 to 0.10. Rect 2 is 15, so you make it 0.10 to 0.25.

Comment: @SledgeHammer No issue, trying to make working RadTimeLine, I didn't hit -1 for your post, If you are referring to that.